# Calendar application

Tags: python, user-interface, calendar

I am making a pretty basic calendar app for my computer to practice working with GUIs and making them interact with code. My first question revolves around the spacing of the calendar. Here is the code I have (it is fully functional, no  bugs):

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import calendar


class main:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.month = IntVar()
        self.year = IntVar()
        self.months = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12)
        self.widgets()

    def getcal(self):
        # Day/Month/Year Computations
        m = self.month.get()
        y = self.month.get()

        # Horizontal/Vertical Spacing for Formatting Calendar Output
        cal = calendar.month(y,m,1,1)
        self.area.delete(0.0, END)
        self.area.insert(0.0, cal)

    def widgets(self):
        # Main Heading
        Label(self.master, text='Calendar', font=('freesansbold', 30), bd=10).pack()
        f = Frame(self.master, pady = 10, padx=10)

        # Month Label:
        Label(f, text='Month: ', font=('freesansbold', 13)).grid()

        # Month Dropdown Selector
        mon = ttk.Combobox(f, width=7, font=('freesansbold', 15), values=self.months, textvariable = self.month)
        mon.grid(row=0, column=1)
        mon.current(0)

        # Year Label:
        Label(f, text='Year: ', font=('freesansbold', 13)).grid(row=0, column=2)

        # Year Entry Box:
        ttk.Entry(f, width=7, font = ('freesansbold', 13), textvariable=self.year).grid(row=0, column=3)
        f.pack()

        # Calendar Display area:
        self.area = Text(self.master, font=('freesansbold', 15, 'bold'), width=20, height=9, bd=15)
        self.area.pack()

        # Get Calendar button
        Button(self.master, command = self.getcal, text='Get Calendar', font=('freesansbold', 15, 'bold'), bd=10).pack()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    main(root)
    root.title('Calendar')
    root.mainloop()
```

So the first question is, how would I make the day numbers line up with the days of the week heading? (I usually just put the year as 2010 because it starts the month on a Monday) The way that it currently is, the numbers are completely thrown off, and I'm a little bit picky about how it looks. It is possible that this question will be answered by the second one:

Second question:
How do I make each of the days of the month a button? I don't really want to have to type this code 31 times to get the spacing of the grid right, i.e., copying the button code and changing the grid numbers. What is a good algorithm to create all the buttons I need, and project the correct numbers on them? I have played around with this, and I have not found anything except typing this stuff over and over again.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Put the grid numbers in a container then iterate over them making a button for each? Or figure out a way to calculate the grid numbers and generate them on the fly in a loop that makes buttons?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To make each day a button, you're going to want to stop using a `Text` widget.

The calendar module has a useful function called `calendar.monthcalendar`, which returns a calendar of a specific month in a matrix (nested lists). If you generate a matrix of buttons, you can then use the output of `monthcalendar` to fill the numbers in the right locations:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import calendar


class main:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.month = IntVar()
        self.year = IntVar()
        self.months = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12)
        self.widgets()

    def getcal(self):
        # Day/Month/Year Computations
        m = self.month.get()
        y = self.year.get()

        # Fill current month label
        self.current['text'] = calendar.month_name[m] + ' ' + str(y)

        # Remove text from all buttons
        for ii in range(6):
            for jj in range(7):
                self.area[ii][jj]['text'] = ''

        # Loop over monthcalendar matrix and fill button text
        for ii, week in enumerate(calendar.monthcalendar(y, m)):
            for jj, day in enumerate(week):
                if day != 0:
                    self.area[ii][jj]['text'] = day

    def click(self, event):
        print(event.widget.cget('text'))

    def widgets(self):
        # Main Heading
        Label(self.master, text='Calendar', font=('freesansbold', 30), bd=10).pack()
        f = Frame(self.master, pady = 10, padx=10)

        # Month Label:
        Label(f, text='Month: ', font=('freesansbold', 13)).grid()

        # Month Dropdown Selector
        mon = ttk.Combobox(f, width=7, font=('freesansbold', 15), values=self.months, textvariable = self.month)
        mon.grid(row=0, column=1)
        mon.current(0)

        # Year Label:
        Label(f, text='Year: ', font=('freesansbold', 13)).grid(row=0, column=2)

        # Year Entry Box:
        ttk.Entry(f, width=7, font = ('freesansbold', 13), textvariable=self.year).grid(row=0, column=3)
        self.year.set(2010)
        f.pack()

        # Label for currently displayed month
        self.current = Label(self.master, text='', font=('freesansbold', 13))
        self.current.pack()

        # Calendar Display area:
        f2 = Frame(self.master, pady = 10, padx=10)

        # Add day indicators
        for i, day in enumerate(calendar.day_abbr):
            Label(f2, text=day, font=('freesansbold', 13)).grid(row=0, column=i)

        # Create empty matrix
        self.area = [ [ 0 for i in range(7) ] for j in range(6) ]
        # Fill matrix with buttons
        for ii in range(6):
            for jj in range(7):
                self.area[ii][jj] = Button(f2, text='', font=('freesansbold', 15, 'bold'), width=4, height=1, bd=0)
                self.area[ii][jj].bind("<Button-1>", self.click)
                self.area[ii][jj].grid(row=ii+1, column=jj)

        f2.pack()

        # Get Calendar button
        Button(self.master, command = self.getcal, text='Get Calendar', font=('freesansbold', 15, 'bold'), bd=10).pack()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    main(root)
    root.title('Calendar')
    root.mainloop()
```

P.S. You used `y = self.month.get()` instead of `y = self.year.get()`, which made your function use the number of the month (1-12) for the year.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I had one follow up question, that is in regard to line 34. (p.s. you forgot the parenthesis after print :) ) I'm assuming this is the part where I would make it do stuff, like for example, when I click a number, it would be under def click(self, event): that I would make it pull up a text box for comments on that day, right?

Comment: Oh right, I use python 2.7 and only changed back the import statements. The `click` function is indeed the place to put the code you want to be executed when a date is clicked. You can use `event.widget.cget('text')` to find which day has been clicked. In combination with `self.month.get()` and `self.year.get()` this gives you the exact date.